# Moving and scaling UIView with UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIView add sub view on self.view.

I want when UIPanGestureRecognizer to right/left/top/bottom is UIView moving and scaling follow touch.

When UIView width/height smaller 0.5 width/height self.view is UIView will dismiss.

Please suggest help me?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have vc - ViewController and your UIView A is a subview of vc. You can add UIPanGestureRecognizer to A. Then drag the panGestureRegonizer to your vc as an action:

```
@IBAction func panGestureAction(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.calculationModeLinear, animations: {
            let location = sender.location(in: sender.view?.superview)
            sender.view?.center = location
        })
    }
```

Here sender.view?.superview equals vc.view. This code snippet will detect the pan gesture, and then will move A so A.center is matching the gesture's location. Note that duration 0.1 is giving smooth animation effect to the movement.

Comment: Thank you very much. For move view with UIPanGestureRecognizer, i have make fine. I am having trouble with scale.